# How to normalize Mat .with 1/255, where Mat is of OpenCV type

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, opencv, objective-c++

I am using `OpenCV`, firstly i converted `UIImage` into `Mat` format & further 
i want to normalize Mat with 1/255(divide each element of Mat with 1/255).
currently i am using

```
outputImageMat.convertTo(outputImageMat, CV_32F, 1.0 / 255.0, 0);//(1)
 //normalize(outputImageMat, outputImageMat, 1/255);//(2)
 circleImage = [OpenCvModel UIImageFromCVMat:outputImageMat];
```

Note: convertTo & normalize is OpenCv built in Methods.

Where circleImage is UIImage type &

For(1) it is giving me Yellowish image

For (2) it is giving me totally blank image.

The output Image should be very light (nearly black image) 
how can i proceed ?,Any Modification, Idea?

Comment: `outputImageMat` is correct. The issue is that you can not visualize it correctly because `UIImageFromCVMat` doesn't support a `float` matrix (and probably you need to swap R,B channels).

Comment: @Miki thanks for your comment, then how can we convert UIImageFromCVMat ?

Comment: Keep `UIImage`s for visualization only, converting from `Mat` only BGR or grayscale images. And do all your processing with `Mat`s